# Why won't Visual Studio Create Database?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I started into this book "Beginning ASP.NET MVC 4" by Jose Rolando Guay Paz and hit a problem straight away. According to the book, once you've created an mvc 4 internet application and run the default template and select the log-in link from the UI , then stop debugging this should create a LocalDB.
When I select "Log-in", I'm met with the following...Server error in '\' application

```
  CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

According the error page (yellow screen of death), its the below line in InitializeSimpleMemebershipAttribute.cs

```
  ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
```

In Visual studio the following is highlighted in InitializeSimpleMemebershipAttribute.cs

```
  LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
```

and the connected message - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
InnerException - The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized.

Its a mvc 4 application running on Visual Studio 2010 on a windows xp machine, this machine is on a network if that makes any difference.
I am familiar with MVC , but mainly the front end , so I'm trying to get clued up on the database creation/connection side of the it.

Web Config connection string...

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=LP-58\SQLEXPRESS;database=HaveYouSeenMe-20140203145852;Integrated Security=sspi" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Tried this one as well but no joy...

```
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-HaveYouSeenMe-20140203145852;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'm sure it's something simple but I can't seem to get it, so if I don't ask at this point I'll just me wasting more time, any help is appreciated

Comment: Setting `Integrated Security=SSPI` will attempt to use your windows credentials to authenticate with your DB. So check to see if those credentials are set as some sort of admin in sql express.

Comment: When I go to connect to local copy of sqlSever - Server type - Databse Engine, Server name - LP-58\SQLEXPRESS, Authertication - Windows Authentication  and my User name is greyed out and password not visiable.....

Comment: And are you able to log in using those credentials? You also need to check under `Security -> Logins` that your credentials are allowed to create databases.

Comment: yes can log in with those credentials, I'm not seeing my name in the list when I expand the logins folder ?...is this the problem ?

Comment: Yes, it probably means you don't have privileges to see them.

Comment: but if I right on Database and select New Database, it allows me to proceed .... and when I try to add a new login, SQLexpress tells me my login already exists ?

Comment: Is your web app outside the network domain of the sql server?

Comment: I don't believe so, I'm running a everything on my local machine, visual Studio and SQLExpress, how can I confirm for you?

Comment: Can you show the code for your `DbContext`

Comment: Thanks @Shoe for all your help turns out one of the names listed in the login folder was mine but it was only when I drilled into the properties and seen the my login-name , so a quick re-name in the folder listings seems to have done it thanks...

Answer (score 0):

One of the names listed under logins was actually mine but had the last machine users name listed.

It was only when clicking on the name and selecting properties that I discovered the log-in name listed was mine.

So a rename of the The name listed in the logins folder listings corrected the error.